Read a dataframe inside map function in a structured streaming query
I have a structured streaming query running as
spark.readStream....
.map(row => 
  spark
    .read("")
    .filter(col("some" === row.some && col(some2) === row.some2)
    .map
    .groupBy
    ....
    ..
    .write()
  )
.writeStream
.format
.....

However, I get errors while trying to do so. Since the code inside map is called on the executor, sc is null. While creating a new spark context via Spark session.builder().getOrCreate(), I also get an error, saying it is not recommended to do this on the executor.
But the way my data is. I have to go through the rows, then process some data bases on row values, and then commit offsets for checkpoints.
Is there an easy way to achieve this?
I understand in the current form, the execution plan is why this is happening. Is there a way to change this so that the reads get triggered on the driver and the resulting rdd get distributed for further processing.

Probably helpful: Link

This only talks about how outer joins are not supported. I don't think I can convert my map into one. Since I have to read a dataset for every row.

Perhaps that is not clear from the example. Let me edit that.

So the dataset is not static in my case.
